# Connecting headphone output of soundcard with speaker amplifier?

Tags: sound-card, amplification

I have a soundcard, but I don't know which model. There are four 3,5mm outputs.

My speaker amplifier is connected to the 3,5mm output which I previously used for some 20 Dollar active speakers and also headphones. Is this the right output to connect the amp to? I'm asking, cause as it can be used for headphones, too, isn't the signal already amplified there and thus it would be better to use a suitable, non-amplified output, if there is one?

Comment: It might be useful to include more details on your motherboard (for on-board audio), the sound card, and the speaker amplifier. It seems like you're asking how to best set up your system and without info on these three items, it is subject to speculation.

Answer (score 0):

If the amplifier is outputting to a speaker (or is acting as the speaker) you should be fine. If the levels seem off, adjust the volume in windows (or your OS if other) first (try about half way for the "normal" level line) then adjust the amplifier &/or speaker's volumes to your liking.